# ListView with CheckBox

Tags: android

I am working on an app as a beginner in android programming.
I have to do a listview of an image, 2 textviews and a checkbox for each row.
I have to implement in the action bar a continue button so when this button is clicked, all the checked checkboxes in the list appears in an alert dialog in another listview.
The problem i am facing is that i don't know how to know which checkbox was checked so i can implement the alertdialog.
Can anyone help me please ?

this is my main activity code:

```
package com.example.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
ListView listView;
ArrayList<ListViewItem> items;
CustomListViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items = new ArrayList<MainActivity.ListViewItem>();
    items.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item1", "Item1 Description"));
    items.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item2", "Item2 Description"));
    items.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item3", "Item3 Description"));
    items.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Item4", "Item4 Description"));
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ListViewItem {
    private int thumbnailResource;
    private String title;
    private String subTitle;

    public ListViewItem()
    {

    }

    public ListViewItem(int thumbnailResource, String title, String subTitle)
    {
        this.thumbnailResource = thumbnailResource;
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public int getThumbnailResource()
    {
        return thumbnailResource;
    }

    public void setThumbnailResource(int thumbnailResource)
    {
        this.thumbnailResource = thumbnailResource;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubTitle()
    {
        return subTitle;
    }

    public void setSubTitle(String subTitle)
    {
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.action_continue:
        doContinue();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void doContinue()
{
// open the alertdialog box depending on the items selected 

}
}
```

and this is my adapter code:

```
package com.example.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.view.MainActivity.ListViewItem;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem>
{
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<ListViewItem> items;
public CheckBox checkBox;
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ListViewItem> items)
{  
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_row, items);

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //System.out.println(position);
    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);
    View rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent, false);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowview.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    imgView.setImageResource(item.getThumbnailResource());
    txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    txtSubTitle.setText(item.getSubTitle());

    return rowview;  
}
}
```

so where and how can i write my code to know which items were selected via the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply click listener on `rowview` and toggle checkbox on that clcik. Also use `setTag, getTag` to update an item whether it's clicked or not. Then provide a method in adapter to return all items with checked tag.

Try like:

// update your getView like

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //System.out.println(position);
    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);
    View rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent, false);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowview.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    imgView.setImageResource(item.getThumbnailResource());
    txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    txtSubTitle.setText(item.getSubTitle());

    rowview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(e){
        @override>
        public void onClick(view v) {
            if(item.getSelected() ){
                item.setSelected(false);
                checkBox set unselected resource
            } else {
                item.setSelected(true);
                checkBox set selected resource
            }

        }
    });


    return rowview;
}
```

// add a method to get checked items

```
public List<ListViewItem> getSelectedItems() {
    List<ListViewItem> selectedItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    for(ListViewItem item: items) {
        if(item.getSelected())
            selectedItems.add(item)
    }
    return   selectedItems;

}
```

Comment: can you show me how to do that ? sorry i am new at this .. i don't know how to toggle the checkbox to the rowview and how to use setTag and getTag.

Comment: its giving me and error on the View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:
Have a parameter on ListViewItem model that keeps checkbox state (a boolean for example).

Implement a Listener for the checkbox view (or the whole row) so that you can update this new parameter whenever the checkbox handles onClick.

Then you can simply use the same Collection (in your case ArrayList items) for the new ListView.

Comment: thanks a lot .. can you just show me how ? i am new i don't really know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is, to add each checked item or the whole View to a ArrayList<> after passing or clickling it to do action.

I don't know what you want to show in the alertdialog, but you can select each CheckBox with checking whether the BOOL `isChecked()` is true.

So you can go through the whole listView by its children and check if the BOOL is true, so you only have the checked items.

Comment: where do i have to implement the BOOL isChecked() method ? and how can i use it and where ? thanks

Comment: You have the object `CheckBox` for example you have this: `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(...); ` then you can check it with `if(cb.isChecked()) { do something }`

Comment: ohh .. and i write this method in the adapter class ? and where and how do i use it ?

Comment: for example when you set an onClickListener you can then in the listener go through all listView children and get the checkbox element and check whether the checkbox is checked or not. then you can do whatever you want with the checkbox.

Comment: but for the onclicklistenner do i set it for the row or the checkbox ?

Comment: it depends what you wanne do. for example if you want to handle those booleans when you sumbit the listview or something like that, you can do it there. i m still not sure what you wanne do with the listview, but you could check the checkboxes whereever you want. but of course you can check thos right when you click on the checkbox. cb.setOnClickListener or cb.onChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class:

```
class ListViewItem {
         private boolean isChecked = false;
         public boolean isChecked(){
         return this.isChecked;
          }
         public void setChecked(boolean checked){
             this.isChecked = checked
          }
```

And in your getView method add this:

```
if (items.get(position).isChecked){
   checkbox.setChecked(true);
}else{
 checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
```

to get all the checked items add it to your adapter class:

```
public ArrayList<ListViewItem> getCheckedItems(){
        ArrayList<ListViewItem> checkedItem = new Arr......

        For (ListViewItem items:item){
           if (items.isChecked){
             checkedItem.add(items);
            }
}
     return checkeditem;
}
```

You must also create a class that implement the onClickListener for your checkbox look at this sample:

```
// private class StatusOnClickListener
private class StatusOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private CheckBox viewHolder;
    private int _position;

    public StatusOnClickListener(final int position, CheckBox _viewholder) {
        viewHolder = _viewholder;
        _position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (viewHolder.isChecked()) {
            List.get(_position).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            List.get(_position).setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}// end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bean_droid .. i will try it now thank you

Comment: you must use it in your checkbox in your getView like this: checkbox.setOnClickListener(new StatusOnClickListener(position,checkbox))